# When using karate.get should functions like callonce be supported?

Tags: karate

I was looking to use something like the following to ensure headers are present before running our scenario, but I am getting an error.  I wanted to verify if this is supported or if there was possibly a different approach I should be looking at?

```
* def authHeaders = karate.get('#(authHeaders)', callonce read('classpath:adapters/authentication.feature'))
```

error received:

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:39 Expected , but found read
karate.get('#(authHeaders)', callonce read('classpath:adapters/authentication.feature'))
```

I tried wrapping the default value for the call in ()'s but received the same error.

Updated samples after first comment:
tried

```
    * def authtHeaders = karate.get('authHeaders', '#(read("classpath:adapters/authentication.feature"))')
    * print authHeaders
```

result

```
01: karate.log('[print]',authHeaders)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "authHeaders" is not defined
```

tried

```
    * def authtHeaders = karate.get('authHeaders', '#(read(\'classpath:adapters/authentication.feature\'))')
    * print authHeaders
```

result

```
01: karate.log('[print]',authHeaders)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "authHeaders" is not defined
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

tried

```
    * def authtHeaders = karate.get('authHeaders', read('#(classpath:adapters/authentication.feature)'))
```

result

```
01: karate.get('authHeaders', read('#(classpath:adapters/authentication.feature)'))
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: <<myRoot>>/src/test/java/adapters/#(classpath:adapters/authentication.feature) (No such file or directory)
```

tried

```
    * def authtHeaders = karate.get('authHeaders', read('#(\'classpath:authentication.feature\')'))
```

result

```
01: karate.get('authHeaders', read('#(\'classpath:authentication.feature\')'))
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: <<myRoot>>/src/test/java/adapters/#('classpath:authentication.feature') (No such file or directory)
```

tried

```
    * def authtHeaders = karate.get('authHeaders', read('authentication.feature'))
```

result

```
01: karate.log('[print]',authHeaders)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "authHeaders" is not defined
```

tried

```
    * def authHeaders = '#(karate.get(\'authHeaders\', callonce read(\'classpath:adapters/authentication.feature\')))'
    * print authHeaders
```

result

```
13:49:07.424 [com.intuit.karate.cli.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] #(karate.get('authHeaders', callonce read('classpath:adapters/authentication.feature')))
```

tried

```
    * def authHeaders = #(karate.get('authHeaders', callonce read('classpath:adapters/authentication.feature')))
```

result

```
01: #(karate.get('authHeaders', callonce read('classpath:adapters/authentication.feature')))
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:0 Expected an operand but found error
#(karate.get('authHeaders', callonce read('classpath:adapters/authentication.feature')))
^
```

Comment: please can you read this once: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions, so yes this is invalid syntax. please read the documentation and examples here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#configure-headers

Comment: Added additional samples based on 1st link.
I understand the use within the second link, but that does not fit my scenario although it may work for authentication headers.  I am looking to use this structure for more than detailed, such as running any scenario that may be missing a necessary piece of information such as a change to object where the object is not already a variable accessible for the scenario.

Comment: mike, really sorry - I give up. there is a lot of incorrect use of karate, so I suggest you read the docs and stick to the examples. if you still need assistance, follow this process, I cannot understand your second comment: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: My second comment was simply stating that I am looking to use this karate.get() expression in more ways than authentication.  I attempted to follow the documentation, but is not very helpful.  It states use #( around the right side of the expression ), which I displayed in numerous ways with no success.

Comment: I completed this in 2 separate steps, since the right side of a get has to be a literal / constant `* def authtHeaders = karate.get('authHeaders',); if (!authHeaders) {karate.set('authHeaders'), karate.call('authentication.feature'))};`.  Definition for karate.get, which could have solved this issue initially - get the value of a variable by name (or JsonPath expression), if not found - this returns null which is easier to handle in JavaScript (than undefined), and an optional (literal / constant) second argument can be used to return a "default" value, ...