# Validating arguments passed to feature file

Tags: karate

Is it possible to validate arguments passed to a feature file?  I have the following line in my subconfig for our IT service level authentication:

```
 karate.log ('portalAuthValues: ', portalAuthValues.sessionId);
  domainAuthResults = karate.callSingle('classpath:adapters/domainsession.feature', { authHeader: loginAuthResults.sessionId, baseUrlDomain: baseUrlDomain });
```

In the feature file, I used a karate.get with a default value to check if the passed authHeaders are present, but this seems to fail

```
Background: Calling authentication
    * print 'portalAuthValues are' 
    * print portalAuthValues
    * def portalAuthValues = karate.get('portalAuthValues', karate.call('classpath:adapters/authentication.feature', { username : username, password: password }))
```

It appears as though the portalAuthValues value that is passed from the config is not recognized, although a value is present as shown in the logs and the value appear to get overwritten:

```
07:31:46.546 [com.intuit.karate.cli.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] portalAuthValues are 
07:31:46.551 [com.intuit.karate.cli.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] {
  "BaseHeaders": {
    "Authorization": "Bearer ...
07:31:46.615 [com.intuit.karate.cli.Main.main()] DEBUG c.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine - over-writing existing variable 'portalAuthValues' with new value: karate.get('portalAuthValues', karate.call('classpath:adapters/authentication.feature', { username : username, password: password }))
07:31:46.630 [com.intuit.karate.cli.Main.main()] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - request:
```

As a result, the initial login authentication call is completed again.  This causes issues as the login auth call is not using the values of the subconfig, but of the default values set in the original config.

Could this be because the portalAuthValues is a JSON object rather than a specific value, or should this passed portalAuthValues value be recognized by the karate.get within the feature file?

Update based on first comment:
So adding the assertion shows the value is definitely present, but it is still being overwritten

```
>>
adapters.domainsession
9650
4
* assert portalAuthValues != null
6
09:53:07.720 << lock released, cached callSingle: classpath:adapters/authentication.feature
09:53:07.734 portalAuthValues:  {
  "BaseHeaders": {
    "Authorization": "Bearer ...
```

Since the value is present, but not recognized by the karate.get call, would this be a new bug?

```
09:53:07.762 [com.intuit.karate.cli.Main.main()] DEBUG c.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine - over-writing existing variable 'portalAuthValues' with new value: karate.get('portalAuthValues', karate.call('classpath:adapters/authentication.feature', { username : username, password: password }))
```

[image: Films called twice and default not honored in karate.get call]

Answer (score 0):

To validate anything in Karate just use `match` or `assert`. For example:

```
* assert portalAuthValues != null
* match portalAuthValues == { some: 'value' }
```

EDIT: since the question seems to be around the behavior of `karate.get()` it works for me:

```
* def data = { foo: 'bar' }
* def result = karate.get('data.foo', 'baz')
* match result == 'bar'
```

Comment: Added code above, but issue does not appear to be with the assertion of the passed values, but with the karate.get function as it is overwriting the value passed in.

Comment: @mike sorry, I'm not able to figure this out with the info provided

Comment: What additional info do you need?

Comment: @mike you can create a working example on github like last time

Comment: uploaded sample to get.  If you run the planets feature files, you will see that the films feature is ran and the captured data is passed correctly to the people feature via the print statement of the passed variable.  You can also see that the karate.get function does not set the variable to the default (1st parameter) passed in, but runs the films call again to set the value for the variable. https://github.com/Mike-c-Jackson/karate-base-config-use-sample/tree/master/src/test/java/api-tests

Comment: @mike I'm sorry I spent some time looking at this and I'm unable to figure out which file I have to look at. I would suggest creating the most minimal way to replicate. what is the question - is it "how to pass data to another file" - or "how to make sure the data being passed is correct" or "how to use karate.get()" - I am totally lost

Comment: If you run the planets feature file, ..demo/src/test/java/api-tests/planets/test/planets.feature, you will see the error.  Added visual image to initial post for reference.

Comment: @mike I'm even more confused. I don't see any "error". I don't understand why `karate.get()` has anything to do with it. I see 2 calls to `karate.callSingle()` and this is VERY unusual, so yes it could very well be a bug or un-supported. please create a minimal example, along these lines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - or hopefully someone else here can help you

Comment: The error is that karate.get is supposed to act as a default value check, in such that if the variable has a value, then use that, else use the default value (second part of the get).  Since the first part of the get in my call has verified the value is being passed in, that passed in value should be used and not the default value. See https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/830

Comment: @mike I edited my answer to add a few lines. it works for me

Comment: I found a solution for the duplicate call being made.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75534828/when-using-karate-get-should-functions-like-callonce-be-supported